# Putting a value from a function into context

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

Adding pagination to my program has caused an existing feature to no longer work properly.

I have tried this

```
cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
return cart_obj
```

and this

```
context['cart'] = cart_obj
return context
```

Both times I got the error message

*name 'cart_obj' is not defined*

[image: name 'cart_obj' is not defined]
[image]

**views.py**

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "products/list.html"
    # added for pagination
    context_object_name='object_list' #Default: object_list
    # print(context_object_name)
    # paginate_by = 3

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
        context['cart'] = cart_obj
        return context
        print("context")
        print(context)

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        request = self.request
        return Product.objects.all()
    
    def get(self, request):
        paginate_by = request.GET.get('paginate_by',6) or 4
        data = self.model.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(data, paginate_by)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
       
        try:
            paginated = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            paginated = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            paginated = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        return render(request, self.template_name, {'DataPaginated':paginated, 'paginate_by':paginate_by, 'cart':cart_obj})
```

I am trying to find a way of putting the value of `cart_obj` in `cart`.

Answer (score 0):

your cart_obj is not define in your get methods, you need to get context before

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
        context['cart'] = cart_obj
        return context

def get(self, request):
        context = self.get_context_data() # get context
        paginate_by = request.GET.get('paginate_by',6) or 4
        data = self.model.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(data, paginate_by)
        page = request.GET.get('page')
       
        try:
            paginated = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            paginated = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            paginated = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

         context['DataPaginated'] = paginated
         context['paginate_by'] = paginate_by

        return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: Thank you, now I am getting the error 'ProductListView' object has no attribute 'object_list'

Comment: I have put my new error here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63236371/productlistview-object-has-no-attribute-object-list