# object has no attribute 'object_list'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I am getting an error and I think it may be for the same reasons Viktor had a problem (['ProductList' object has no attribute 'object_list'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37675704/productlist-object-has-no-attribute-object-list))

On Viktors post AKS wrote -

You might be getting the error on following line in get_context_data() of the super class:

```
queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)
```

The get method of `BaseListView` sets the `object_list` on the view by calling the `get_queryset` method:

```
self.object_list = self.get_queryset()
```

But, in your case, you are calling `get_context_data()` in `get_queryset` method itself and at that time `object_list` is not set on the view.

I reviewed my trace back and saw code that AKS had mentioned.

```
  File "C:\Users\HP\Django Projects\EcommerceProject\products\views.py", line 48, in get_context_data
    context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\HP\DJANGO~1\ECOMME~1\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\list.py", line 131, in get_context_data
    queryset = kwargs.pop('object_list', self.object_list)
AttributeError: 'ProductListView' object has no attribute 'object_list'
[03/Aug/2020 18:20:21] "GET /products/ HTTP/1.1" 500 90906
```

Here is my code

```
class ProductListView(ListView):
    model = Product
    template_name = "products/list.html"
    # added for pagination
    context_object_name='object_list' #Default: object_list
    # print(context_object_name)
    # paginate_by = 3

def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request)
    print("get context data")
    # context = {}
    context['cart'] = cart_obj
    return context



def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
    request = self.request
    return Product.objects.all()

def get(self, request):
    
    paginate_by = request.GET.get('paginate_by',6) or 4
    data = self.model.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(data, paginate_by)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
   
    try:
        paginated = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        paginated = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        paginated = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    # context={}
    context = self.get_context_data()
    context['DataPaginated'] = paginated
    context['paginate_by'] = paginate_by

    # return render(request, self.template_name, {'DataPaginated':paginated, 'paginate_by':paginate_by, 'cart':cart_obj})
    return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

**Issue Fixed**

I slightly modified the `get_context_data` function in the class `ProductListView(ListView):`

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.object_list = super().get_queryset()
    context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: `self.object_list` does not exists, that is simply the name of the item passed to the context.

Comment: How can I rectify the issue? I kind of understand what you are saying but I am not really sure how to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact issue are you trying to solve or what exactly are you trying to solve through the code?

Do you want to set a context object name or do you want to retrieve data from the Product model?

If retrieve data from Product model, you can just use the objects.filter.

If this line : `context = super(ProductListView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)` is the issue you are trying to solve.. try moving the `def get_context_data` to be within the `ProductListView` class.

Comment: When I display products for the user to buy, I want to display either a 'buy it now' or 'remove from cart' button depending on if the item is already in the cart or not.

Comment: cart_obj, new_obj = Cart.objects.new_or_get(self.request) checks if a cart exists for this specific user exists. If one doesn't then it makes a new one.